# assertLog not catching logging

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I have this test program running in Python 3.8.3

```
import unittest
import logging
class logging_TestCase (unittest.TestCase):

    def test_logging(self):
        with self.assertLogs() as cm:
            logging.Logger('test').error("A test error message")
```

Then I run this:

```
% python -m unittest dummy.py
```

And get this.  Notice that my test message is being written out, but it is in the wrong format. Maybe this is why the context manager is missing it?  This is all my code, so I don't see where I'm changing the format.

```
A test error message
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_logging (dummy.logging_TestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/raysalemi/PycharmProjects/pyuvm/tests/dummy.py", line 7, in test_logging
    logging.Logger('test').error("A test error message")
AssertionError: no logs of level INFO or higher triggered on root

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
(base) raysalemi@WriteNow tests % cat dummy.py
import unittest
import logging
class logging_TestCase (unittest.TestCase):

    def test_logging(self):
        with self.assertLogs() as cm:
            logging.Logger('test').error("A test error message")%
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this broken in 3.8.3?
I am accustomed to writing in 3.6.

Comment: I have tested the logger on the command line and it is still not formatting the messages correctly. I think this is why they are not being caught.  As far as I know I have not changed the logging handler, certainly not so it would be changed on the command line.

Answer (score 6):

As you can see in the message, the logging is checked on the root logger - this is the default, if you don't provide a logger. As you don't use the root logger, the assertion fails. You have to pass the logger that you are testing:

```py
class LoggingTestCase (unittest.TestCase):

    def test_logging(self):
        logger = logging.Logger('test')
        with self.assertLogs(logger) as cm:
            logger.error("A test error message")
```

As for the format: that depends on how the logger is configured.

Comment: Yup. That was it. Thank you.

Comment: Using python 3.11, running your code raises the same error as OP's: `AssertionError: no logs of level INFO or higher triggered on test`, any idea what's wrong ?

Comment: No idea - works fine for me with Python 3.11, just tested it.

Answer (score 0):

If with the `logger = logging.Logger('test')` the error is still present:

```py
AssertionError: no logs of level INFO or higher triggered on test
```

Try to change it from `Logger` to `getLogger`

```py
class LoggingTestCase (unittest.TestCase):

    def test_logging(self):
        logger = logging.getLogger('test') # <---- the change is here
        with self.assertLogs(logger) as cm:
            logger.error("A test error message")
```